# port conflict while using Process class to start a process

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, process

I'm trying to start a process in an ASP.NET Core MVC Controller. The process I want to start is another ASP.NET Core Web API. To achieve this, I use `Process.Start("filePath")` but this gives me the below error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:7134: address already in use.
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint endpoint)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in --filePath\sampleAPI\Program.cs:line 119`
```

Controller code:

```cs
public IActionResult StartNewProcess()
{
    Process.Start("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\PermissionAPI\\PermissionAPI\\PermissionAPI\\bin\\Release\\net6.0\\PermissionAPI");
}
```

I tried to change the port number in appsettings and launchsettings and I tried to pass the port number as an argument but both ways did not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you change the port, does the value in the error change accordingly? Are you sure you are not doing anything that could cause multiple instances of the server to start?

Comment: You are in an asp.net process starting a different process also been an asp.net process? And both Asp.net processes use different ports and you checked that?

Comment: @JonasH yes, port number changes and the error still occurs. no im not doing any thing that can create multiple instances. the process that is being started inside the asp.net core mvc application trying to use the same port as of that mvc.

Comment: @Ralf, 1. yes both asp.net processes. 2. yes when i run them separately they use separate ports.

Comment: Guessing. Process Start will use the current working directory and the started process will find launch setting relative to that folder. You may try explicitly setting the working directory for the started process. Process.Start has an overload with a ProcessStartInfo parameter where you can specify the working directory.

Comment: Besides that is weird starting another web server this way. What prevents calling the endpoint doing that twice?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what are you trying to achieve here. Why would you need to start another web app from your main web app?

Comment: Based on your description and error message it seems that , the web API you're trying to start is attempting to bind to a port (7134) that's already in use by another process. So have you tried to use other port if the error still persisted?